# Bubnov-Galerkin method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to get how Bubnov-Galerkin method works and solve the equation: $$-(x^2u'(x))' + 2u(x)=1+x, u(0)=0, u(1) =0$$
Algorithm says that we need to find functions $u$ and then using them approximate solution. But I don't exactly get how do find those functions.

Comment: Are you sure about these initial conditions? Given the general form of the solution, the identity $u(0)=0$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-x^2u''-2xu'+2u=1+x \tag 1$$
Solving the associated homogeneous ODE : $\quad -x^2U''-2xU'+2U=0 \quad$ leads to :
$$U=c_1x+c_2 x^{-2}$$
The search for a particular solution of the inhomogeneous ODE : $\quad -x^2u''-2xu'+2u=1\quad$ obviously gives $\frac{1}{2}$

The search for a particular solution of the inhomogeneous ODE : $\quad -x^2u''-2xu'+2u=x\quad$ isn't so obvious. Since $x$ is a solution for the homogeneous ODE, we look for a particular solution on the form $xy(x)$.

$-x^2(2y'+xy'')-2x(y+xy')+2xy=x \quad\to\quad -x^2y''-4xy'=1$

With $y'$ on the form $ax^{-1}$ one find $a=-1/3$. Then, from $y'=-x^{-1}/3$ a particular solution is $y=-\ln(x)/3$

Thus, the general solution of equation (1) is :
$$u(x)=c_1x+c_2 x^{-2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}x\ln(x)$$

The condition $u(1)=0$ implies $c_1+c_2+\frac{1}{2}=0 \quad\to\quad c_1=-c_2-\frac{1}{2}$
$$u(x)=c_2 (x^{-2}-x)+\frac{1-x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}x\ln(x)$$

For $x\to 0\quad u\to\infty$ if $c_2\neq 0$.

If $c_2=0$ then $u(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ which is contradictory with the condition $u(0)=0$. So an exact solution doesn't exist.

We look for an approximate solution in changing the condition to the approximate condition $u(\epsilon)=0$ with a small $\epsilon$.

$0=c_2 (\epsilon^{-2}-\epsilon)+\frac{1-\epsilon}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\epsilon\ln(\epsilon) \simeq c_2 (\epsilon^{-2})+\frac{1}{2} \quad\to\quad c_2\simeq -\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$

The approximate solution 
$$u(x)\simeq \frac{1-x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}x\ln(x)-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} (x^{-2}-x)$$
satisfies exactly the ODE and condition $u(1)=0$ and guaranties an approximate agreement to the condition $u(0)=0$, in fact $u(\epsilon)=0$. The smaller we set $\epsilon$, the better is the agreement.

Another approach should be to introduce the Heaviside function in the solution, through solving with Laplace transform method. But I think that isn't in the scope of the problem.

[image]